# how to install ironpython on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, mono, ubuntu-14.04

I need to install iron-python.I clone the iron-python package from github and run make.now i got this error
[image]
Is there are any other way to install iron-python ?
How can i fix this error? need a quick help

I download the package form this

```
git clone https://github.com/IronLanguages/main.git IronLanguages
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to compile on Mono 3.8, though I had to remove [this section](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/587184f47f67d6b5471338f66df03a972a0bc239/Solutions/Common.proj#L51) from Common.proj. It isn't needed and looks like a left-over/workaround for earlier mono versions.

Another thing I had to fix was to uncomment [this else clause](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/587184f47f67d6b5471338f66df03a972a0bc239/Languages/IronPython/IronPython.SQLite/c%23sqlite/pcache1_c.cs#L738), or it would complain about `pGroup` being uninitialized.